# Running same job on multiple instances in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to run the same job on multiple instances without including it in all the instances i.e including it in only one instance?

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do this. First you have to create master server [(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175104.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175104.aspx)) and then create a master job (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190662.aspx) that will be downloaded to defined target servers.

Regards,

Dean Savović

Comment: avoid using multiple links in answer, as the url may change or link may not work after some time.